# Trigger before insert into increments sequence by 2

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6. I have the following sequence and table:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE measure_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    START 1
    CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE measure (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('measure_id_seq'::regclass),
    time_stp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    val double precision NOT NULL,
    pollutant character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    station character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT measure_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
```

The table "measure" is partitioned into different tables based on the values of the "pollutant" and "station" columns.

For this, I have a trigger that is executed before new data are inserted into the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_on_measure()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$

DECLARE format_station TEXT := lower(replace(new.station, ' ', ''));
DECLARE format_pollutant TEXT := lower(replace(new.pollutant, ' ', ''));
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(
        $f$
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (
            check (station = %L AND pollutant = %L)
            ) INHERITS (measure)
        $f$, 
        concat('partition_measure_', format_station, '_', format_pollutant), 
        new.station,
        new.pollutant);
    EXECUTE format(
        $f$
            INSERT INTO %I (time_stp, val, pollutant, station)
            VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L)
        $f$, 
        concat('partition_measure_', format_station, '_', format_pollutant), 
        new.time_stp,
        new.val,
        new.pollutant,
        new.station
        );
    RETURN NULL;
END $$;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_measure
    BEFORE INSERT ON measure
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_insert_on_measure();
```

Inserting new data into the table "measures" creates the right children tables. For example when I insert the following data:

```
INSERT INTO measure (time_stp, val, pollutant, station)
    VALUES ('2015-01-01 01:00:00', 32.4, 'O3', 'Station 1');
INSERT INTO measure (time_stp, val, pollutant, station)
    VALUES ('2016-01-01 01:00:00', 54, 'NO2', 'Station 2');
```

it creates the tables:

- partition_measure_station1_o3
- partition_measure_station2_no2

The problem that I have is that my "id" column is incremented by 2

```
id time_stp                 val  pollutant station
2  "2015-01-01 01:00:00+04" 32.4 "O3"      "Station 1"
4  "2016-01-01 01:00:00+04" 54   "NO2"     "Station 2"
```

Instead, I would like to have:

```
id ...
1 ...
2 ...
```

It seems that nextval('measure_id_seq') is executed twice on each INSERT.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**: The answer provided by JGH was correct. For reference, here is the trigger edited:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert_on_measure()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$

DECLARE format_station TEXT := lower(replace(new.station, ' ', ''));
DECLARE format_pollutant TEXT := lower(replace(new.pollutant, ' ', ''));
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format(
        $f$
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (
            check (station = %L AND pollutant = %L)
            ) INHERITS (measure)
        $f$, 
        concat('partition_measure_', format_station, '_', format_pollutant), 
        new.station,
        new.pollutant);
    EXECUTE format(
        $f$
            INSERT INTO %I
            VALUES (%L, %L, %L, %L, %L)
        $f$, 
        concat('partition_measure_', format_station, '_', format_pollutant), 
        new.id,
        new.time_stp,
        new.val,
        new.pollutant,
        new.station
        );
    RETURN NULL;
END $$;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_measure
    BEFORE INSERT ON measure
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_insert_on_measure();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the trigger, when you do the insert statement to the partitionned tables, you must pass the new.id value. If you do not, the default is used, which is a second call to the sequence generator.